# How to Select specific link from Database using query in Datatable

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

i have 117 links of paging=3 like

```
http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=22& p=2
```

and 3 links of paging=3 like

```
http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=19&p=3
```

i want to select just links of p=2 through Data table in C# sql ,
contains and Not IN query is not working

Comment: Please post your table structure, an expected result, and an attempt at the  query to help people out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query to get specific results i guess it will help you out

```
select * from tablename WHERE columnName LIKE '%&p=3%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the query but there was kind of problem with my insertion method